# Virtualhost Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have Tomcat and Apache web server. by MOD_JK I configure Apache to send request for `http://127.0.0.1/cas` to Tomcat.
`http://127.0.0.1/cas` works correctly and Tomcat response to it.
now I want this `https://127.0.0.1/cas` to work, (SSL).

I search it and found that I need Virtualhost on Apache that send requests to Tomcat, my question is how can I create a SSL Virtualhost?
and should I remove all configuration that I create before this for `http://127.0.0.1/cas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One vhost entry will reference :80 and the other :443

So for example (stripped down version) This assumes you never want to login with non-ssl.. So redirect to ssl

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName login.domain.com
    Redirect / https://login.domain.com/

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName login.domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/login.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/login.domain.com.key
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP

    ProxyPass / http://1.2.3.4:8080/cas
    ProxyPassReverse / http://1.2.3.4:8080/cas

</VirtualHost>
```

That also assumes tomcat has the ip of 1.2.3.4 and running on port 8080

Comment: why you don't use mod_jk? it's not useful for this issue?

Comment: I don't want mod_jk running on the same web nodes that do php

Comment: what is wrong? I get this error from Mozilla Firefox "the page isn't redirecting properly", it's because loop in redirection, how can I solve it?